# Play mp4 file from webapp directory

Tags: grails, video

I want to play video file in my application, so I write below code for the same

```
<video width="640" id="videoPlayer" style="background:black" autoplay controls>
    <source src="/cam01/2017-11-07_17-04-25.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>
```

The cam01 folder is in Tomcat's webapp directory (/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/webapps/cam01), but I'm getting following error in console log

[image]

Even when I'm trying to hit url http://localhost:8080/cam01/2017-11-07_17-04-25.mp4 directly on browser to see video, I'm getting following error...

[image]

Comment: `.mp4` might not supported for your browser use `.webm` instead. Or else update your browser.

Comment: what happens when you run the app from console or in IDE?

Comment: which browsers you tried?

Comment: @Durga : My requirements does not allow any format instead of .mp4 file.

Comment: @devbd : the same issue which I post and I tried with different browsers also. currently I'm testing with firefox 52.2.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can play videos on a page from the local directory or remote directory:

```
<video src="[ YOUR VIDEO ].mp4"
controls
width="720" height="480">
Your browser does not support the video element, please #D try <a href="videos/VID_20120122_133036.mp4">downloading the video instead</a>
</video>
```

Please check the compatibility of the browser that your trying to test playing in through:

https://caniuse.com/#search=video

The current state of support for the element is below:

[image]

*It is also preferred if you could play webm format instead of mp4.*

If it still does not work make sure you have flash installed.
https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Tried your code but same issue...

<video src="/cam01/2017-11-07_17-01-25.mp4"
                   controls
                   width="720" height="480">
                Your browser does not support the video element, please #D try <a href="/cam01/2017-11-07_17-01-25.mp4">downloading the video instead</a>
            </video>

Comment: Try installing Flash for Firefox, IE uses a different version of Flash than Firefox needs: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video 

I've tried this example that properly working on my browser. But Only not working is my application.